# how to see the parsing speed of log file for every line and every 10sec

Tags: python

I have a log file and I want it to be parsed every line and in 10 seconds I need to know the speed of the parsing. But my code is parsing the data from the log file, so it only takes the data of the log, not speed of the log file .

my python code:

```
import re
import schedule
import threading
import time
log_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/ip.txt'
output_file ='/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/puu.csv'
name_to_check = 'MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED'
start = time.time()
class Log_minning:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_counter = 0
        self.time_counter = 1
    def get_userdata(self):
        user_att = []
        list_usr = []
        counterr = 0
        with open(log_file) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                if name_to_check in line:
                    date = re.search(r"([12]\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])+"
                                     "(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))", line)
                    date = date.group()
                    )
                    ip = ip.group()                        
                    user_att.append(date)                       
                    list_usr.append(user_att)
                    counterr = counterr + 1
                    # print("get " + username + " " + date + " " + time + " "
                    #       + ip)
        self.data_counter = counterr
        return list_usr
    def procces(self):
        self.get_userdata()
    def check_length(self):
        speed = self.data_counter / (self.time_counter * 10)
        print("Speed =" + str(speed) + " data/sec")
        self.time_counter = self.time_counter + 1
    def log_control(self):
        schedule.every(10).seconds.do(self.check_length)

    def schedule_triger(self):
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(10)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lm = Log_minning()
    lm.log_control()
    t1 = threading.Thread(lm.procces())
    t2 = threading.Thread(lm.schedule_triger())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

my output is:

```
Speed =11.7 data/sec
Speed =5.85 data/sec
Speed =3.9 data/sec
```

This is the result I am expecting from my code:

```
92748.4 line/s
91840.8 line/s
91867.1 line/s
92661.2 line/s
```